# <input type="file" name="img" accept=".jpg"> is retriving only image name insted of full path, how to fix it?

Tags: html

`<input type=file name=img accept=".jpg">` is retrieving only image name instead of full path, how to fix it?

for example: if image URL is `c:\images\img.jpg`, It taking only `img.jpg`, instead of **full path**. it works fine in older version of browsers like iexplorer.. But not working in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Please provide little more info..

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav

Comment: This is a security issue. To prevent access to someones computer data, browsers mask the file path. You cannot access this anymore, only with activeX or Firefox/Chrome with elevated privileges. A simple Google search would've provided you with this answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav#answer-15201258

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$filePath = realpath($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
```